# OAuth 2 with JWT in Web API with 1-N callers from the same customer

Tags: c#, security, authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

Yes, the title of this question is horrible but after 5 minutes of trying to figure out how to word it I moved on!

I am starting the design phases of a stand-alone authorization server (C#, Web API, Azure) for a software platform that is receiving a significant overhaul. I read the always great articles by Taiseer Joudeh (http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity) on the subject and have the implementation mostly mapped out in my head. The external users of the authorization server (app developers who will be consuming the services from various end points) will have a portal that they can log into and manage their accounts, white list IP addresses, select their API version (similar to how Stripe does it) and other various administrative tasks.

What has me hung up are the two different real world (happens today) scenarios where a caller has more than one unit on their access access the API and processing transactions. Below is a summary of the current requirements (could change, nothing is set in stone if there is a good argument I have not considered) as well as the two scenarios I am struggling with.

Question: Do I allow my authorized customers (customers with access to an account on the auth server to define 1-N number of "apps" that will have their own refresh/auth tokens...

**Facts:**

- Many of my clients run multiple servers which process transactions through the platform. These may be dedicated on prem servers or worker roles in Azure and everything in between.
- The implementation must support long periods of time between API calls without the need to fully reauthenticate. Some clients make calls once a month.
- I like Box's implementation: Refresh tokens are valid for 60 days, access tokens are valid for 1 hour. Each new access token provides a new refresh token.
- The customers within the portal will have to "whitelist" their IP addresses and new access tokens (and with them new refresh tokens) will only be handed out to a request coming from one of their whitelisted IPs.
- The token must contain the version number for the application for which the token is being requested for use in the destination app (controller selection). See SO for more details.
  Every "refresh" of the access token issues a new refresh token.
- The refresh tokens are not "burned" until the first successful call with the new access token (in case the new access token is lost in transit, the client can obtain a new access token with the previous refresh token).
- I have not committed to this yet but it seems like a value add with little downside given the whitelisted IP addresss.
- Access tokens will have a very short life (15 mins). This is both for security purposes as well as API version migrations since the version will be in the token.

**Concerns:**
Two different scenarios in a multiple caller scenario:

- **On Prem Servers:** To me it makes complete sense in this scenario to allow the customer within the authorization server portal to define 1-n number of callers, each representing one of their servers which will be making requests. In this scenario there is no shared cache and it would be very difficult (if not impossible) to allow a shared refresh/access token. What would happen the first time multiple servers received a 401?
- **WorkerRole (Azure):** In contrast to the On Prem Server config, it would be very difficult to support multiple refresh/access tokens without some config file wizardry where each scalable unit was aware of its place in line (i.e. what instance number it happened to be). In this scenario the customer would have access to shared cache and could implement a concurrent collection or the like to keep track of the current refresh and access token and the first caller to hit a 401 could block the others while the new access token was obtained.

*** Update based on Brice's Answer ***

With respect to client/application credentials there are in fact both but I wanted to clarify what my current plans are which now include Thanktecture. I used it back in the WS-Fed (v2 I believe) days and have not looked at it for OAuth2 but I will.

Each customer that has been granted access to the API (think of these as the parent accounts who then have many child accounts under them who do not have API access) will have a login to the API portal (likely Identity 2.0 based w/an MVC or Angular front end). In this portal they will be able to manage their account (set API version for a particular application amongst other things). Here is where they will be able to "create" application credentials assuming that dynamic registration is not implemented. They will not be using the Identity 2.0 portal account creds for their clientID. I will most likely be generating these credentials dynamically (clientId and secret) with some strong random password generation code.

The question heart of the my initial which you touched on was whether I should allow the creation of one and only one client ID/secret and not enforce a one active refresh/auth token per clientID constraint OR allow them to create 1-N and create a 1:1 between that particular client ID/secret.

It is very unlikely that I would ever need multiple different permissions/roles for specific customer against a specific application. In other words if CustomerA had the ability to call POST against a specific URI, that will always be true and if it changes it would change for that customer across the board. As a result my plan was to set application specific permissions at the customer level (that identity 2.0 portal account I referred to above) and that creates an abstraction of sorts if I go with the 1-N clientID/secrets under the account. Each of those clientID/secrets would inherit those permissions.

I am ashamed to admit as I had started crawling down the proverbial rabbit hole that I neglected to consider the possibility of allowing a 1:Many relationship between the clientID/secret and active refresh/auth tokens. I kind of had it in my head that they would be tied together and would only ever exist as a pair. In this scenario, if a user had 3 active agents running against the API, the third one to obtain an auth token (and as a result a new refresh token) would have broken the ability for the other two agents to obtain a new auth token without fully reauthenticating since agent 3's refresh token was the last one granted.

In the 1:Many scenario each and every authenticating agent coming from the white listed IP, using the clientID/secret would get a valid refresh/auth token for their own use. This really solves all of the problems I described but reduces the visibility a little on "who" the caller is or how many callers there really are if they are behind a load balancer.

Of course the balance I am trying to strike is that of solid security coupled with a relatively painless implementation for the end user who today is familiar with a key-value-pair in a json object implementation for authentication and authorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having developed a similar architecture I can see you supporting one of two scenarios (or possibly  both):

- Allow customers to share application/client credentials across multiple instances (servers or worker roles) of the application.
- Require customers to use a unique set of application/client credentials for each instance of an installed application.

You don't mention use of client or application level credentials, but I am assuming these are in use rather than supporting unregistered clients. In other words when a customer registers their application (or application instance) and supplies their IP addresses, you return a unique client ID (and often a client secret). This client ID and secret is then used by the customer's application to request an access token and refresh token combination.

An access token and refresh token combination should be unique for each application instance. It is also acceptable (and somewhat common) for a single application instance to request multiple active access/refresh tokens. An example is when you have two API endpoints that might require a different authorization level, the application could request two access/refresh tokens each with a different set of scope values (authorization) to be used with these endpoints. In your scenario each application instance (server or worker role) would request it's own access/refresh token combination and independently recycle these. The more interesting question in my opinion is whether these application instances share the same client credentials, or use a unique set.

The OAuth 2.0 Threat Model encourages use of installation specific client secrets (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-5.2.3.4). It uses the wording "An authorization server **may** issue separate client identifiers and corresponding secrets to the different installations of a particular client" (emphasis mine). However, I have found in practice that there is little to stop a client from reusing client credentials for multiple instances with native and mobile applications.

With the additional protection of white-listing customer IP addresses, I think you would be fine without using unique client credentials per application instance. That being said you should fully consider all threats unique to your system that may attempt to exploit this as a weakness. One possible way to address this would be to use a dynamic client registration process to automatically issue client credentials for each new application instance. See OpenID Connect Dynamic Client Registration 1.0 (http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-registration-1_0.html) or the draft OAuth 2.0 Dynamic Client Registration Protocol (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-dyn-reg-21) as examples of this. Again this may be difficult to enforce that a customer uses dynamic client registration, rather than simply reuse a single set of application/client credentials.

In closing, may I suggest rather than designing an OAuth2 authorization server from scratch that you look at the excellent open source Thinktecture IdentityServer (https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v3) (no affiliation) platform as an extensible starting point.

Comment: Brice,

For starters thank you for such an thorough response. You touched on every one of my concerns, even ones that I did not articulate fully. I have updated my question above to further flesh it out and reflect on your statements. I will mark your response as the answer but if you have any more insight please share it as I believe this could be a helpful dialog for others.

Comment: Thanks for the additional detail. One option to improve visibility is to include a claim with the caller's IP address on the access token. As this can be spoofed and is not always forwarded through proxies it is not ideal to use for authorization purposes, but it may still be useful as additional information to distinguish clients. As you stated, having a separate client ID per application deployment will give you the best visibility. This may be tough for your customers using Azure worker roles without a dynamic registration option.